# Changing the Joomla site Logo to point to another page instead of home page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a site in Joomla which I cannot find the File that will allow me to change the Link of the Site logo to point to another page instead of the Home page.
I went into template extension but I find no option, can someone point me to the file please.

I am using the youretro Joomla Template the peach style. 
inside peach.css

```
#logo a{
    background:url(../images/peach/logo.png) no-repeat left top;
```

do I need to add link in here? will it overwrite the old one?

[www.divine-culture.com](http://www.divine-culture.com)

Comment: We won't be able to help by looking at the site. The logo is either 1) built into the template settings, 2) coded directly into the template files, or 3) in a module. Are you using a commercial template?

Comment: Also, you're talking about deviating from a widely-understood standard on the web. Consider whether you'll be confusing your users.

Comment: @isherwood I am using a commercial template, and the reason I am deviating the user it's because my site is a sister site to a another site which is the main one, and I want the user to go back to the main by clicking on the logo.

Comment: Ok, so share something about your template in the question, please. We can't help you without more information.

Comment: I am using youretro Joomla template

Answer (score 0):

The [**docs for the template**](http://yjsimplegrid.com/documentation/basics/changing-your-website-logo.html) have all you need to know. Very few Joomla templates would require you to modify php files to change a logo, and you can't change a link with CSS.

> There are 2 ways of changing your website logo. Overriding existing logo.png located in site_root/templates/template_name/images/style_name/ folder or uploading new logo trough template manager.

Option 1:

> Now replace existing logo.png file name in site_root/templates/template_name/images/style_name folder with new logo....

Option 2:

> Go to template manager tab name Layout hover over existing logo than click on tool icon the logo settings panel will drop down. Click on Select button and select or upload your new logo....

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question

> I am using the youretro Joomla Template the peach style. inside
>   peach.css
>   ...
>   do I need to add link in here? will it overwrite the old one?

This is a CSS file and isn't any help if you want to change the default home page link.

A couple of ideas for you.

If you know how to work with jQuery, or if your template lets you add your own custom jQuery, you could try

```
$('#logo a').attr('href', 'http://www.alternate-link.com');
```

This will overwrite the home page link with http://www.alternate-link.com

Alternatively, you could open the template > youretro > index.php file, locate the HTML for the header and then the logo link. You might be able to manually change this HREF. You can also do this via the backend from Extenstions > Template manager > templates tab > Template > Edit main page template.

Not that if you do either of the second options, there's the risk that your customisation will be overwritten if you update the template.

Good luck!

Comment: the issue with index.php  which I checked in the past as well is that I don't see any HTML for the header..there is no header.

Comment: @JFA if you can't find HTML for the header in your template > index.php file, one possibility is that it could be coming from a module